# Blackberry Version Detection javascript code

Tags: blackberry, version

I publish .net web application to blackberries. In 9700 and lower versions, There is no problem, but after 9780, styles look very big in blackberry. Html table cell fonts are very big

I want to use different css file for versions greater than 9780, but How can I detect blackberry version?

I find this, but I cant detect 9780, anyone knows howe can I detect 9780 and greater versions?

```
var x= navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var y = (x.indexOf("blackberry9") != -1);
```

And Im new to bbery, version 9 means bberry 9000 and greater, is it true?

Comment: up to now there are Version 7.0 only. Check it in google type as "Blackberry api 5.0 reference"  like this 6.0 or 7.0

Answer (score 1):

Various blackberry models use different `User-Agent` formats.  There are several different formats that you need to check for in order to handle the widest range of devices.  Check [this page](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/BlackBerry/) for examples.